# Elastic search map multiple fields to a single field

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elastic search provide a functionality to map different fields to a single field and use that single field for search.

For eg _all refers to all the fields in the docs.

Similarly do we have any mapping configuration to define a field which would be referring to multiple fields.

Eg : I have a field called Brand,Name,Category.

I need to map Brand and Name to a single field custome_field.

I want it during mapping time and not during query time. I know cross fields does that during query time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [copy_to functionality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html). It acts just like a custom `_all`. See [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-all.html) more about this:

> In Metadata: _all field we explained that the special _all field
> indexes the values from all other fields as one big string. Having all
> fields indexed into one field is not terribly flexible though. It
> would be nice to have one custom _all field for the person’s name, and
> another custom _all field for their address.
>
> Elasticsearch provides us with this functionality via the copy_to
> parameter in a field mapping:

```
PUT /my_index {
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "first_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "copy_to":  "full_name" 
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "copy_to":  "full_name" 
                },
                "full_name": {
                    "type":     "string"
                }
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Updated link for [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html)